# Do libraries usually come with header files?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

I am currently making a small library of reusable code out of what has proven useful over the time and I'm wondering how are libraries usually deployed? I was under the impression that a .dll and .lib would be enough, but then, how do i reference the classes and functions? Is it common for a library to also come with a lot of .h files or there is a more elegant solution?

What about deployment of the actual application that uses the library? Once linked statically do I also need to send the .dll file or the content of the library is copied in the program?

Comment: How would anyone be able to use your library without knowing what functions/classes is in the library? That's what the libraries header files are for.

Comment: Libraries pretty much always come with one or more .h files. You say "a lot" of .h files - Often libraries try to have one .h unless they offer functionality in lots of areas as it makes it much easier to use but some have one per class still for example. Some have one common .h file that just includes all of the smaller ones to help out the user.

Comment: I don't think its worth an answer but I thought it might be interesting. In `c++` you can even encounter libraries that comes only as headers! `Eigen` or parts of `boost` are two good examples. IMO when you start using templates it is actually easier to do this way. It even starts to become hard if not impossible to deliver binaries for templated libraries.

Answer (score 6):

As a rule of thumb, you gather all your public methods, which you want to expose to end users, in a group of headers called API. At this point, you should make a distinction between internal headers and API headers and you will see that your header file number (API headers) will decrease and management of file structure will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 5):

There are three essential components when you deliver a library:

- several versions the library itself: `.so` under Unix, `.dll` and `.lib` under Windows, with versions for debugging, optimized versions, possibly multithreaded and single threaded, possibly a version with profiling activated... *and* support for static linking (`.a` under Unix, `.lib` under Windows, but not the same one as you need to link the DLL),
- the headers which define your external interface, and
- the documentation, explaining *how* to install and link the libraries, which compiler options are required for each version, etc. as well as the documentation of the library itself (pre- and post-conditions for every function, etc.)

Anything less, and the client won't be able to use it.

Regarding deployment, again, this should be documented.  If the client links the library statically, then nothing should be required; if he links it dynamically, then he will need to deploy the `.so`/`.dll` files as well.